# Why I have to use a " , " when ever I add something to a tuple in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning python 3. I came up with the term called *"Tuple"*. When I have to add something to a tuple, I have to add a " **,** " at the end. Otherwise, it gives me an error.

a = ('alpha', 'bat', 'call', 'note')
a + ('new',)  # Why I have to use that **','** after **'new'**?

Comment: You should include the error message in the body of your post and explain why that error message text does not answer your question

Comment: I mean if you want, you can convert it into a list like this: `a = list(a)` and then insert an element 
`a.append('new')` and then convert it back into a tuple
`a = tuple(a)`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to append a non-tuple item to a tuple you get met with the following error message

`TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

According to the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

`A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,).`

The reason for this is because tuples contain 2 items so you usually don't want to *only* append single items to a tuple- might as well use a list if that is your goal. If you must add a single item tuple you have to essentially construct it as if it a two item tuple and the syntax to do that in python is by adding a comma to a single item.